# implication of homogeneity of degree -1

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How do I prove that if $x(p)$ is homogeneous of degree -1 then there must exists a constant $a>0$ such that $x(p) = \frac{a}{p}$? I can't seem to connect $x(p) = \alpha x(\alpha p)$ with what I need to prove at all.

Comment: Is $x$ a function? Define homogeneity of degree $-1$. Essentially, you've got to provide context.

Comment: yes it is a function. I just defined homogeneity of degree -1: $x(p) = \alpha x(\alpha p)$ for any nonzero $\alpha$

Comment: Suppose $x(p) = \alpha x(\alpha p)$ for all $\alpha,p$. Set $p=1$, and think : can I take $a = x(1)$?

Comment: oh dang i'm dumb. thanks!

Comment: Answer the question yourself and close it.